# App crashes of abandoned memory

Tags: ios, memory, instruments, abandoned-memory

I am encountering an memory problem. It sounds like I have what is known as abandoned memory and/or a reference cycle.  I am trying to clear this problem for about 2 month and cannot get out of this long tunnel.  I have used apple's interments to find out the place where most memory is used and VM:Image IO_PNG_Data is using 44MB when crash. I drilled deeper and points out that main. m is pointed out 100 percent. I do not get what is going on.  I am new to iOS and I really need help.  You can see my whole code from [this](https://github.com/laryufk/Helper/tree/master) link. I do not have anything that does point out to my code exept the main.

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
//This line below is pointed out             
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
//This line above is pointed out

        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not with main.m. Look at the other end of the stack trace.

Comment: I can't find anything else that is useful that points to my code . [This](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qn3wa0&s=5#.UmnnqZFgKAE) is my stack trace

Comment: Are you testing on a real iOS device or in the simulator? Use a real device if you're not already.

Comment: I am testing on a real device.